# Is there any way to speed up this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables one being a copy of the other. (I have to remove records that no longer exist in the parent).  Running this query works, but requires about 1 min to complete. I know the NOT EXISTS is faster because I won't be running the sub-query for each row, but doesn't return any results.

```
SELECT mlscopy.listing_listnum 
FROM mlscopy 
WHERE mlscopy.listing_listnum 
NOT IN (SELECT mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum FROM mls_cvrmls)
```

I'll clarify, the problem here is the parent changes over time, and I have to remove/add records from the child. So I'm stuck on removing from child where listing_listnum doesn't exist in parent.

Here is the not exists query

```
SELECT mlscopy.listing_listnum 
FROM mlscopy 
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum FROM mls_cvrmls)
```

Figured it out

```
SELECT mlscopy.listing_listnum
FROM mlscopy 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum 
FROM mls_cvrmls
WHERE mlscopy.listing_listnum = mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum
)
```

Comment: "I know the NOT EXISTS is faster because I won't be running the sub-query for each row, but doesn't return any results." - Can you include your `not exists` query? If anything, it should be more reliable than the `not in` query, due to the possibility of NULLs being inside the excluded dataset.

Comment: off point of your question. but how about adding a trigger to the parent table to auto-maintain the child table.?

Comment: Hmm.. Tom Kyte won't say EXISTS will be faster. http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:4144857323705644::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT mlscopy.listing_listnum 
FROM mlscopy A
NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM mls_cvrmls B
    WHERE B.listing_listnum = A.listing_listnum
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this variation and see if it's any better:

```
SELECT mlscopy.listing_listnum 
    FROM mlscopy 
        LEFT JOIN mls_cvrmls
            ON mlscopy.listing_listnum = mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum
    WHERE mls_cvrmls.listing_listnum IS NULL
```

Comment: Not sure it will speed it up, however this is probably how I would have written the query.

Comment: @AndreDublin - then your original query wouldn't return results either since they are logically identical.  They are just two different ways of approaching the same result set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE INDEX i_listnum ON mls_cvrmls(listing_listnum ASC)
```

Trying to rewrite the query with a `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` will probably not make that much a difference because the query optimizer could figure that out.

However having a mean to quickly find a row in `mls_cvrmls` by `listing_listnum` can only improve the performance (but it will take additional space).

[About index creations](http://use-the-index-luke.com/).

Another option could be:

```
SELECT listing_listnum FROM mlscopy
 MINUS
SELECT listing_listnum FROM mls_cvrmls
```